# Error in linking to Css and js file in index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flask

I want to link my css file in my index.html file. The structure of my project is:

```
MyWeb
  Views
      -> index.html
  css
      -> style.css
  js
      ->jQuery.js
```

I tried the following relative href links but nothing worked.

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../js/jQuery.js"></script>
```

Here is the link to the website hosted locally: http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: If the structure is as you showed, that should work. Can you check your webserver log to see what URLs are being requested? Are you seeing 404 errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Yes, I see the 404 errors. "GET /js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: What is the path of your css file?

Comment: I am Using Flask framework. Should be something different for flask?

Comment: can you share URL how you run you index file in browser ?

Comment: check permision on folders

Comment: The existence of a `Views` directory implies that you are using a server side framework which is going to change the URLs to something that is much harder to imply from looking at your file system. You need to look at the URLs you are using, not your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

its relative to the root

Comment: Absolute paths make it difficult to relocate your project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ../ in href

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 0):

The html files are dynamic if you are using Flask Framework. Try something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
```

Found here: [Flask framework intro](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-pythons-flask-framework--net-28822)

Answer (score 0):

assuming your folder structure is as follows

`your app
      templates
      static
          style.css
  app.py`

or you can also do it like this

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" type="text/css" />`